# Possible to replicate -march=native compilation in vm?

Tags: gcc, compilation, g++, virtual-machine

I am considering building my binaries in a VM to isolate the building process from my physical machine, however I read that KVM for example disables things which do not have virtualization support, fair enough.
However, this could theoretically affect compilation in i.e. gcc when using `-march=native`.
As I understand it `-march=native` turns on specific fatures in gcc so, is it possible to export these flags/features to build the binary in a vm instead of directly on the machine, getting the optimization benefits without having to clutter the machine?